# Multiple File Uploads for a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, uploadify

I have implemented multiple file uploads for existing records as seen here https://github.com/websymphony/Rails3-Paperclip-Uploadify

I would like to know if it is possible to implement multiple file uploads when creating a new record.

Since we need flash to do the multiple file uploads, how would it be possible to associate the uploaded files with the record if the record has not yet been created.

I have thought of a hack-ish way to essentially make a "draft" and update it. However, I hope there is a better way to do this.

Comment: you don't "need" flash for multiple uploads. Js is fine

Comment: btw, there is no better than the kind of hackish way you present

Comment: thanks for you quick response. How can you implement the ability to select multiple files with js?

Comment: See here: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Wow, more people need to be made aware of this. Why would ANYONE use flash if they knew about this? Thank you, by far the most amazing piece of information i've learned about this month.

Comment: Please post your original answer with a link mentioning that and I will accept it so people coming across this page will atleast learn about they way to do it without flash.

Comment: :) whatever could help people avoid flash ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no better than the kind of hackish way you present:

- creating orphans objects and give them parents later or delete them (sad huh? :) )
- creating parent object by default, add some confirmation field in the form so that you know what objects really have an owner, delete the rest.

BTW, you don't "need" flash for multiple uploads, see here: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/. But there are still some points you need to be careful.

1. Don't forget to remove appended array after you define the file field with "multiple". For example: replace "photo[image][]" with "photo[image]".Otherwise file uploaders like "carrierware" will not be working.
2. If you are using rails 3.2.13, the appended array will always appear no matter whether you set the name to be without appended array. You can use "file_field_tag" to resolve this problem. Please refer this issue to: https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails/issues/36.

For the association:

1. You need to create a hidden text field which contains IDs of images that will be associated to the record you are going to create.
2. Upload images by "jquery-fileupload"(it is ajax), then get IDs of images from response bodies.
3. Set these IDs to the hidden field.